# C# Constructor overloads: new object.FromOtherObject()?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, overloading, initializer

I have two different types of nodes, I need to be able to convert between them in a relatively easy fashion. I was thinking of doing this in the constructor as it would make code a lot cleaner.

```
NodeA nodea = new NodeA();

NodeB nodeb = new NodeB.FromNodeA(nodea);
```

I've been googling for a couple hours and haven't been able to find a way to do this. The best solution I've come up with is;

```
public NodeB() { }

public static NodeB FromNodeA(NodeA theNodeA)
{
    NodeB b = new NodeB();
    b.Value = theNodeA.value;
    // etc..
}
```

But this makes code look a little more funky like so;

```
NodeB b = NodeB.FromNodeA(nodea);
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this:

```
NodeB b = new NodeB().FromNodeA(nodea);
```

Edit;
Or is the static method I've already done the more (traditionally) correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Why not use [conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) like `(NodeB)a`?

Comment: I hadn't actually even considered doing it that way and that'd make it even cleaner, unfortunately that wouldn't necessarily yield a copy of the object and they do need to be different in my implementation.

Comment: why not just overload the default constructor so: `NodeB  b = new NodeB(nodea);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just have a constructor with a `NodeA` parameter:

```
NodeB nodeB = new NodeB(nodeA);
```

... but having a factory method is also a pretty idiomatic solution. It has various benefits, including being able to have multiple methods with different names but the same parameter types - e.g.

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(...)
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(...)
```

It *also* allows the method more flexibility:

- It could return null in some cases (e.g. for null input)
- It could return a reference to an existing object
- It could return an instance of a subclass (e.g. `Encoding.GetEncoding`)
- You can convert the method group to a delegate, which is handy for LINQ operations (no need for a lambda expression)

One upside of making it a constructor is that if you have a subclass of `NodeB`, that could have a constructor which *also* takes a `NodeA` and chains to the `NodeB(NodeA)` constructor. It's hard to achieve the same thing using the factory method approach without code duplication.

And as per Alessandro's comment, you could have a user-defined conversion operator, either explicit or implicit. I would be *very* careful with implicit conversions though - they can feel like a great idea at the time, but end up leading to code which is unclear later.

Finally, you could also have a `ToNodeB()` method on `NodeA` instead - either implemented directly, or as an extension method.

So to round it all up, here are the options for how the "user code" might look:

```
NodeA nodeA = ...;
// One of...
NodeB nodeB = nodeA;                  // Implicit conversion
NodeB nodeB = (NodeB) nodeA;          // Explicit conversion
NodeB nodeB = new NodeB(nodeA);       // Constructor
NodeB nodeB = NodeB.FromNodeA(nodeA); // Factory method
NodeB nodeB = nodeA.ToNodeB();        // Instance or extension method on NodeA
```

Comment: Another option could be using `ToXXX` pattern (probably as extension method), e.g. `var nodeB = nodeA.ToNodeB();`. I guess that has the same benefits as static `FromXXX`.

Comment: @IvanStoev: True - I might as well be reasonably completist :)

Comment: I prefer the readability of the .FromXXX method compared to overloading the object constructor to accept the other node as an argument/param.

Comment: @MisterNad: Yes, me too. I think it's a generally nice pattern.

Comment: I'll just accept this as an answer that the static "factory method" is the proper way of doing this. Thanks for the quick replies. :)